# Life as a PhD student

Tags: phd, research-assistantship, research-group

I completed my Master's in Chemical Engineering recently as an International student in the US and now I wanted to go for a PhD as well in the same field.I completed a few Volunteer research work for a few professors to build up experience and gain vital skills necessary for research.One thing that I noticed was the lack of direction in research. While the PhD students I worked under were great, they would just give me a problem and tell me to solve it without any guidance or direction. I had no prior experience with the research topics in question and I had a really tough time to figure things out and as a result it was quite stressful.

I wanted to ask if this is to be expected in a PhD position as well.

Comment: One might hope for some guidance, but the point of the PhD is to learn how to do research with minimal guidance.

Comment: @JonCuster Unfortunately, the result of "minimal guidance" is this site: minimally guided and frequently plainly misguided students end up here searching that _normal_ guidance that their PhD supervisor _should_ have provided as part of their work.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - sorry I wasn't clear. The point is that, at the end of the PhD, you can do research mostly on your own. Some guidance is good, and necessary, but that guidance is more how to start doing it on your own, not actually step by step what to do. I have seen cases where there was too much help throughout the PhD by the advisor, leaving a freshly-minted PhD unable to do the work expected of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much guidance you get depends on your advisor. Some give a lot, some give none at all. The latter is not the ideal. Some will give you a problem to work on (or several) and others expect you can come up with your own. The latter is not the ideal.

Part of your experience is due to the fact that PhD students have little experience as yet in advising.

Most advisors, I think and hope, and closer to the ideal, will assist you in coming up with a *suitable* problem and with help along the way. But they will also expect a lot of initiative on your part.

Becoming a good researcher isn't something you necessarily learn how to do on your first outing. You should get pretty far along on the learning curve while doing a doctorate, but there will still be things to learn and refinements you can make.

But, if you are getting in to the process at the beginning, look for an advisor who suits you and your ability. Some people will actually *want* no assistance, but most will want at least some guidance throughout. Don't choose an advisor randomly or for the wrong reasons. It is an important first step.

Comment: Yes +1 plus if they don't see any use of helping you they will not provide you with help. I experienced on my skin. Benefits.

Comment: Heh. You are so right about profs helping. Especially for really prestigious profs with too many students. One of my profs described his PhD under the Great Man (GM). He once gave a talk on his PhD research in front of the whole group. The GM was in the front row, asking good interesting questions. At the end of the talk the GM came up to him and said "That was a really good talk. Who is your PhD supervisor?" "You are Dr. GM." "Oh! Oh! Well come see me in my office tomorrow and we'll chat."

Comment: @puppetsock, the story may be apocryphal, or at least legendary. I've heard it also. The opposite story is the GM who told his student "I don't mind writing your dissertation for you, but I'll be damned if I'll explain it to you when I'm done."